# Javadoc tooltip view lacks buttons (show in web explorer, etc.) in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, tooltip, javadoc, eclipse-mars

I am using Eclipse Mars in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. As I hover over the methods, in the tooltip popup I can see the Javadoc, but the button that used to be below the Javadoc content are missing. I cannot access to a HTML view of the Javadoc.

What is the fix of this? I guess it's OS-specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It's a some-how bug in Ubuntu with Eclipse.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=456786

Basically it's solved by tweaking between GTK versions.

Note that due to the existence of this bug in Eclipse [Ubuntu 16 LTS - Eclipse window preferences not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827762/ubuntu-16-lts-eclipse-window-preferences-not-working-properly]), the GTK version must be set to 2 (in my case `3` is ok too) and you have to install `libwebkitgtk-1.0-0`, not `3.0-0`. I have not tested `2.0-0` because that's a lot to download.

So, to put it together, you have to set in `eclipse.ini`:

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

Or:

```
--launcher.GTK_version
3
```

before the line of

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
```

And, open the terminal and install:

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

And restart Eclipse to see Preference tree and Javadoc web view both work.